# Detecting (not classifying) moving objects in noisy sky images

Tags: python-3.x, image, opencv, video, object-detection

I'm using Python3 and OpenCV and I want to detect and track arbitary objects in image sequences (i.e. video).

Let's say I have a sequence of images captured from some camera. The camera is fixed at some location and pointed at the sky. For arguments sake, let's say I am interested in birds (I'm actually interesed in anything moving, whether bird, plane, baloon, kite, someone's slipper, etc.). When an object (or multiple) flies into the frame, I want to detect (i.e. put a bounding box around) and track it.

**Constraints:**

I don't want to train models on images of everything I might find in the sky because:

- It will take ages
- I don't have the images here are loads of differentobject types and I don't want to make assumptions about what might appear in the image (what if someone throws their slipper? I still want to detect and track it)
- I don't want to make any assumptions about the shape, size (might be very small, depending on how far away), color, brightness, or speed (i.e. across frames), aircraft, etc.
- Some objects may go behind, in front of, or pass through
  clouds...

**Approaches tried:**

- Contouring and thresholding: This works when fine when the background is static (i.e. no clouds) or when there are few clouds (such that thresholding will remove them). However, when the background is noisy (i.e. cloudy, potentially with several cloud layers), the contour algorithm detects the clouds...
- Optical Flow: Slow. Not sure how to identify the 'anomaly'. Won't work if the object is stationary e.g. a drone or balloon.
- Image differencing: Doesn't work with clouds because they move and create too much noise.
- Background subtraction: Didn't remove the clouds when they were moving rapidly or when there were multiple cloud layers. Also, won't work in cases where the object of interest is (or nearly is) stationary (e.g. a drone).

Purely for illustrative purposes, here is an example image with a bunch of objects, which could be birds, planes, paper bags, someone's cat, etc.:

[example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/shucU.jpg)

Comment: "background subtraction". can distinguish slowly changing background from anything that doesn't fit the "model" of slowly changing background. at least one approach uses mixtures of gaussians. that's smarter than simple differencing. -- can I please have a video of a cat and a slipper being thrown across the sky

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz That reminds me -- I did try background subtraction! However, again, this didn't work for clouds as they can more rather quickly. And besides, what if the object, as I mentioned is stationary (e.g. a drone)? I'll get to work making that video for you.

Comment: ok then, "saliency". mysterious stuff but highlights "outliers"

Comment: So you want to detect "anything"... aren't clouds and stars "something"? What about detecting/segmenting pixels of blue sky, clouds, etc. very well and treat regions of non-standard-sky-stuff as being objects of your interest?

Comment: @Micka Sure, but what if the object is similar in color to a cloud or the sky? Clouds, sky, stars, etc. could be considered 'background', but I don't know how to go about defining their characteristics so that they can be 'filtered' out or ignored.

Comment: semantic segmentation DNN (with a lot of work for annotation). If the object looks like background, you wont be able to detect it (with any visual method). If it looks similar to the background, your segmentation or background detection has to be good enough. In the end, your whole task seems to be quite hard and maybe it would be better to go with radar, lidar or stereo vision right from the beginning.

Comment: @a_coder have you found a good solution? I am looking at smoke in the sky, but it keeps getting distracted by moving clouds.